# Workbox PWA customize cache storage chunks

Tags: webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox, code-splitting

#### Context

I've just started learning about PWAs therefor my knowledge is very limited. I currently have an application with React and Webpack. To turn this into a PWA I've decided to use Workbox.

I've managed to create a basic setup and it behaves as a PWA. I checked lighthouse.

But, I do wonder about the Cache Storage. I have split my chunks on route level. Meaning, one route is one single chunk. When visiting a particular route, I fetch the particular chunk.

When viewing the Cache Storage, I can see **every** chunk (route) in there. To me it seems as Workbok is ignoring me splitting chunks on the route level. To me it *feels* wrong, but I don't know if this is the standard behaviour.

[image]

#### Question

Should it work this way? Or could I only cache the chunk (route) I'm currently on? I don't know if this is standard or not.

I appreciate all the input I can get.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using [precaching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching), and you have an integration with your build process set up where a list of all of your chunks are fed into Workbox's list of files to precache.

That's, generally speaking, fine, and it means that your web application is likely to work offline. After your users download your chunks during service worker installation, they won't have to make any future network requests for those files (unless the chunks change).

That being said, you might not want to precache *everything*, especially if you have a lot of chunks, chunks that are for routes that most users will never visit, or if you know that you'll be doing lots of deployments, making the lifetime of any given chunk fairly short. There's more detail about those considerations in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595559/385997).

The syntax for configuring which chunks are included in the precache manifest depends on the build tool you're using; if you're using [`workbox-webpack-plugin`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW) for instance, there are  `include`/`exclude` (taking in webpack-style filters) + `chunks`/`excludeChunks` (taking in chunk names) options that can control that.